# R nrow function returning NULL or 1

Tags: r, string, matrix, indices

This should be very simple but I cannot resolve it. I derive what I think is a matrix from the str_match_all function. It appears this is not the case, despite its  appearance. I am able to extract the timestamp value from the first row of the 'matrix' by hard coding the indices in sapply [1,2]. I want to do the same thing for the last entry in the matrix and thought I would easily be able to extract the number of rows in the matrix to do this e.g. [nrow(sm),2], but cannot! See below:

```
sm <- str_match_all(regex_text, regex_list[row, "regex_pattern"] )
      print(sm)
#This gives me this (which is good):
#      [[1]]
#      [,1]                                       [,2]               [,3]                      
#      [1,] "09/08/2014 13:01CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing" "09/08/2014 13:01" "CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing"
#      [2,] "09/08/2014 13:06CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing" "09/08/2014 13:06" "CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing"
#      [3,] "09/08/2014 13:08CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing" "09/08/2014 13:08" "CONTENT_ACCESS.preparing"

#Get the first timestamp
      start_t_stamp <- sapply(sm, function(x) x[1,2])
      print(start_t_stamp)
# Also good, I get [1] "09/08/2014 13:01" 

#Get the last timestamp. How do extract the 'number of rows' in sm?      
#This returns NULL 
      print(nrow(sm)) 
#transform to matrix??? 
      t_sm <- t(sm)
#This then prints "[1,] Character,9" 
      print(t_sm)
#Therfore this prints 1      
      print(nrow(t_sm))
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `str_match_all` returns a list of character matrices.

Comment: Right! So what would you suggest?

Comment: If you have only one element in your list like here, you could do `nrow(sm[[1]])`, if more `sapply(sm,nrow)`

Comment: What you show as `sm` is not a `matrix`, it is a `matrix`-in-a-`list`, as indicated by the leading `[[1]]`. There is no logic to `nrow` of a list, no matter how many elements it has in it, period. Similarly, `t` cannot work on a `list`, it must have a `matrix` (or easily-coerced-to-matrix, such as a `data.frame`). Bottom line: you have a `list` and must always deal with it as such. It might be beneficial to start your code with `sm <- str_match_all(...)[[1]]` so that the rest becomes more natural to you (though this may change with different data dn patterns).

Comment: Many thanks! They both seem to work for me. Excellent.

Comment: Not sure how to close off the question. Thanks to both of you!